# Quasi-separatedness as a topological condition on the scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $X$ be a scheme. Is it true that the morphism $X\rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{Z}$ is quasi-separated iff the intersection of two quasi-compact open subspaces of the underlying space of $X$ is quasi-compact (so in particular, quasi-separatedness is a purely topological condition)? If the answer is positive, what is a published reference where this is proved in detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. A reference is EGA IV, première partie, Proposition (1.2.7), b'), page 228.

[Numdam link](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1964__20__5_0)

Comment: It seems to be an error in the statement of (1.2.7), c), see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4716228/394668).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess that it has remained unnoticed because it works for an affine cover which is used most of the time. But it is good to have it sharp.

Comment: it seems that the condition of quasi-separatedness is only ever formulated for schemes,  even though it's a purely topological condition ... or maybe there's another word for it in point-set topology?

Comment: See Kempf: "Some elementary proofs of basic theorems in the cohomology of quasi-coherent sheaves" Rocky Mountain J. Math. Volume 10, Number 3 (1980), 637-646. (http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmjm/1250128841). In this paper the underlying spaces of quasi-compact and quasi-separated schemes are called *quasi-noetherian*. A space is quasi-noetherian if it possesses a basis (closed under finite intersection) of quasi-compact open subsets and is itself quasi-compact. I much prefer the terminology *concentrated*.

Answer (score 2):

Another reference is [Tag 01KO](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01KO) in the Stacks project (note that when $S$ is affine the hypothesis that the two opens map into a common affine is empty).

Of course, the condition that the intersection of any two affine is quasi-compact, is equivalent to the condition that the intersection of any two quasi-compact open subsets is quasi-compact.